# Where can I find posing guides & resources online?

Tags: portrait, web, studio, posing

What resources are available online to give ideas for poses. Is there some type of catalogue of common poses?

Comment: Would you be interested in book recommendations too?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/what-portrait-posing-rules-do-you-recommend-for-studio-photography

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What portrait posing rules do you recommend for studio photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/what-portrait-posing-rules-do-you-recommend-for-studio-photography)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly:  I strongly second @kacalapy with his recommendation of [Digital Photography School](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=837&q=posing+site%3Adigital-photography-school.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=).

Second, here are a few sites I've found:

- Free Digital Photography Tutorials have a couple of nice pages (lots of clear examples nicely explained [here](http://www.freedigitalphotographytutorials.com/advanced-tutorials/35-photography-poses-tips-tricks-guidelines-part-1/) and [here](http://www.freedigitalphotographytutorials.com/advanced-tutorials/35-photography-poses-tips-tricks-guidelines-part-2/)
- Jonathan Souer has a step-by-step guide [here](http://www.jonsouer.com/posing.html)
- I know this isn't online, but my go-to reference is actually a book on wedding photography, [The Master Posing Guide for Wedding Photographers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Master-Posing-Guide-Wedding-Photographers/dp/1584282517/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1295603629&sr=8-2-catcorr) by Bill Hurter.  He explains lots of principles and practice with plenty of example images.  Anything by Bill is worth considering in this area.
- To answer your request for a catalogue of poses, another book: [500 Poses for Photographing Women](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Poses-Photographing-Women-Michelle-Perkins/dp/1584282495/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1295605129&sr=1-1) by Michelle Perkins.

Finally, I carry a cribsheet with me which contains the following advice:

1. Check BACKGROUND
2. Stand subject THREE QUARTERS to light
3. WEIGHT on back foot
4. FACE 7/8 to camera
5. HEAD tilt slightly (near shoulder for ladies, far shoulder for men)
6. EYES -> camera
7. ARMS away from body (lift elbows / hold something / hands in pockets)
8. SHOOT slightly down on subject

I hope that's some help.

Answer (score 7):

You can find hundreds of poses [HERE](http://www.herrickphoto.co.uk/poses.html). Another good place for information is [DPSchool](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/portrait-photographys-power-posing-part-i-the-components). You can also find some tips [here](http://www.stnphotography.com/tips.html#positioning), just scroll down some.

Answer (score 0):

See this question right here on this site:

[What portrait posing rules do you recommend for studio photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/what-portrait-posing-rules-do-you-recommend-for-studio-photography)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend buying a fashion magazine subscription or just flipping through one at the bookstore/library. You can get a lot of inspiration out of that.

I would advise that these aren't very helpful if you're looking to do traditional portraits. They're very applicable if you're trying to shoot fashion, or execute an edgier look.

Another resource would be portrait paintings. Any good art history book will have a catalog of great portraits with excellent classic poses.